# Animate every EditText one by one

Tags: android

I have a login screen with some EditText TextView and Button what I want to do is when the login screen is created I want to animate the first EditText from top to bottom then the second EditText from top to bottom after the first EditText is animated, so it should look like all the views are animating from top to bottom one by one.

Comment: share your code

Answer (score 1):

This is kinda ugly but it'll work.

```
 float pixels = 20f; 
 view1.animate().translationY(pixels).setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            view2.animate().translationY(pixels).setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    view3.animate().translationY(pixels);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1
Animation scaleDown = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(youContext, R.anim.scale_down);
ImagView v = findViewById(R.id.your_view);
v.startAnimation(scaleDown);//Start Animation

Step 2 Set Animation listener

Step 3 On Animation end start animated next view like above

so on.....